# Subtracting Data of current row from Next row in Sql

Tags: sql

I was trying to get the difference of data from subtracting row 1 from 2. As I am not good in SQL, So I've tried but facing issues to get the correct query.

I have a table where data of some cases stored based on different cities and date.
I have given them rank based on partition by State Name and order by Date in ascending so that if there is need the I can use the Rank column.

I want to Subtract the Confirmed_cases_data of Ranking 1 from 2, 2 from 3 and the subtracted data will store in the Confirmed cases per day column having RANK 2 and 3 respectively.

**I have also used the Lag function but what it does, it also subtract the data between 2 different states also.**

Query:

```
select state_name, confirmed_cases,
confirmed_cases - coalesce(lag(confirmed_cases) over (order by confirmed_cases), 0) as Confirmed_cases_per_day
from table
```

**Please help to get the correct query.**

**Image of the Table has been attached.**

[image: Table Data]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `PARTITION` in your `OVER` clause to get `LAG` to only look at that states data:

```
lag(confirmed_cases) over (partition by state_name order by confirmed_cases)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6c2349cc7746c24f6265a49b5b23dfb9)

Note you can generally give a default value for `lag` to avoid the `coalesce`:

```
lag(confirmed_cases, 1, 0) over (partition by state_name order by confirmed_cases)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ec86f0130d6c62f5c22fc212daaa5ae7)

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick. Thanks for your quick and solid response!!